# Booting a diskless Debian system using bonding, bridging, and iSCSI

Tags: iscsi, bridge, debian-wheezy, bonding, initramfs

I'm trying to build my personal holy grail: booting my Debian Wheezy KVM server diskless from a iSCSI target and the only configuration needed on the diskless server is the iSCSI parameters in the NIC ROM. The rest of the config should all be `inside' the iSCSI LUN.

The system has two NICs that are connected to a switch that supports LACP. So, I want to boot the machine over the bonded interface, that is also inside a bridge `vmbr0`. Although this combination isn't exactly working.

Because I read that the iSCSI connection should not be interrupted after boot (for example by reconfiguring the interfaces), I tried to set all my IP configuration before boot (in the kernel parameters/cmdline).

The iSCSI boot part is handled by the ROM of my Broadcom dual-port NIC. This seems to work nicely: grub is started and boot continues after that. In my grub configuration, I have this:

```
linux /vmlinuz-2.6.32-26-pve root=UUID={iscsi-disk-uuid} ro  quiet bond=bond0:eth0,eth1:mode=802.3ad,lacp_rate=1,miimon=100,xmit_hash_policy=layer2+3 bridge=vmbr0:bond0 ip=192.168.15.4::192.168.15.1:255.255.0.0::vmbr0:off
```

When grub launches the kernel, I get these errors:

```
ipconfig: vmbr0: SIOCGIFINDEX: No such device
ipconfig: no devices to configure
... repeated 10 times...
/scripts/local-top/iscsi: .: line 426: can't open '/run/net-vmbr0.conf'
```

And I'm dropped in the initramfs shell, where I find that `bond0` is not configured at all (the `bonding` module is however loaded) and `vmbr0` neither (the `bridge` module is apparently builtin).

When I make the scope smaller, by excluding the bonding configuration, with this grub line:

```
linux /vmlinuz-2.6.32-26-pve root=UUID={iscsi-disk-uuid} ro  quiet bridge=vmbr0:eth0 ip=192.168.15.4::192.168.15.1:255.255.0.0::vmbr0:off
```

Also here, `vmbr0` is not created.

So it seems to me that Debian Wheezy's initramfs isn't configuring both bonding and bridging. `brctl` is available in the initramfs, `ifenslave` on the other hand is not.

What is there to do about this? Or are my kernel parameters (cmdline) not supported/allowed? Or should I consider another booting sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is defenitely interesting question and here is how I did a trick. My configuration is about the same as yours: Proxmox booting via iSCSI bridged interface. My grub boot line looks like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0 ISCSI_INITIATOR=iqn.2007-08.com.example.client:client ISCSI_TARGET_NAME=iqn.2005-10.org.freenas.ctl:proxmox ISCSI_TARGET_IP=192.168.11.3 ISCSI_TARGET_PORT=3260 root=UUID=04709453-9d82-47d6-a898-81ea6408f88e ip=192.168.11.1:::255.255.255.0:client:vmbr2:off"
```

To boot with this grub configuration I need to start the bridge before grub mounts root. I make it by assigning a script in /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules like this:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:30:48:94:61:ec", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", NAME="ens6f0", RUN+="/bin/brctl-iscsi ens6f0 vmbr2"
```

this /bin/brctl-iscsi script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

ifconfig $1 mtu 9000 up
brctl addbr $2
brctl addif $2 $1
ip link set dev $2 type bridge forward_delay 0 stp_state 0
```

I also need a initramfs hook to put this script in initrd:

```
root@proxmox-2:~# cat /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/brctl_iscsi
#!/bin/sh -e

PREREQS=""

prereqs() { echo "$PREREQS"; }

case "$1" in
    prereqs)
    prereqs
    exit 0
    ;;
esac

. /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hook-functions

copy_exec /bin/brctl-iscsi    /bin
```

And finally in /etc/network/interfaces I have this for iscsi interface and its bridge:

```
no-auto-down ens6f0
no-auto-down vmbr2

iface ens6f0 inet manual

iface vmbr2 inet manual
    address  192.168.11.2
    netmask  255.255.255.0
    bridge-ports ens6f0
    bridge-stp off
    bridge-fd 0
    down ifconfig vmbr2 down; brctl delbr vmbr2
#iSCSI network
```

That's it
Regards, Dmitry